# Where can I find the passuk / commentary about Animals instinctively doing their business without turning their back to the Beith Hamikdash

Tags: sources-mekorot, animals

I've tried to look for it but couldn't find the reference, where it's said that Dogs & other animals instinctively position themselves in South/North (and other directions but not with their behind facing East)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the dog is north of the bais hamikdash they might face east - west while if east or west of the bais hamikdash, they might face north - south.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect match, but you might be thinking of [Yoma 3:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.3.8?with=Bartenura), which says that the bull of the Kohen Gadol on Yom Kippur is positioned so that it won't relieve itself towards either the Temple or the Altar.

Comment: Is that reason given in the Mishnah itself?

Comment: Thank you Heshy! That might be the beginning of my answer, maybe there's commentaries around it! Thanks so much again! Brakha veAtzlakha to you & your loved ones!

Answer (score 2):

This is a recent answer from science, not religion. See https://www.pbs.org/newshour/science/dogs-poop-in-alignment-with-earths-magnetic-field-study-finds

Excerpt/summary: Researchers measured the direction of the body axis in 70 dogs of 37 breeds during defecation (1,893 observations) and urination (5,582 observations) over a two-year period. Directional preferences of dogs under different MF conditions were analyzed. Results: Dogs preferred to excrete with the body being aligned along the North–South axis under calm Magnetic Field conditions.

Comment: Thank you a lot Phil! That's actually one of the article I wanted to reference as well, so thanks so much for digging that out, you're so kind, lots of blessings!